# annotation Nullable in context class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.5.3

It's been a few days at Android Studio 3.5.3 make a problem , the source code of Activity class and ParentClasses of this class (ContextThemeWrapper ,ContextWrapper and Context class) is been red 
the messages error of this problem are like:

```
Cannot resolve symbol android.annotation.nullable is not public in Android.annotation ...
```

[image]

Please help me
ever resolve of this problem that was said in sites , I tried it
but cannot resolve this problem.

Comment: try   Invalidate Caches/Restart.. maybe it will solve your issue..

Comment: I had done this before, but the problem didn't work out
I even did the project Clean project / Rebuild project  several times but it didn't work out

Comment: Can you add the full logs from the build, after Invalidate Cache / Restart?

Comment: after Invalidate Cache / Restart , the side of all log of build is a green tick but in side of this log that write blow is Prohibited sign          
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild 
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl                                                                                 :app:compileDebugAidl 
:app:compileDebugRenderscript                                                                                       :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio, go to File > Invalidate Cache / Restart.

That should fix your issue.

Comment: I had done this before, but the problem didn't work out